# How can I find all the specific child gameobjects by name and add them to a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class SpinableObject
{
    public Transform t;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;

    public void RotateObject()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed)
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed)
            slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    [Header("Global Rotation")]
    [Space(5)]
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;
    public List<GameObject> allObjects;


    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Rotation Mode")]
    [LabeledBool("Global Rotation", "Individual Rotation")]
    [SerializeField]
    bool _rotationMode = true;

    [Header("Individual Rotation")]
    [Space(3)]
    public SpinableObject[] individualObjects;


    private void Start()
    {
        allObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach(Transform t in transform)
        {

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (_rotationMode == false)
        {

            foreach (var spinner in individualObjects)
                spinner.RotateObject();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.Count; i++)
            {
                RotateAllObjects(allObjects[i].transform);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RotateAllObjects(Transform t)
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed)
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed)
            slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

Inside the Start i want to add the child objects by name not tag "Propeller"
I have 4 child objects: "Propeller1" , "Propeller2" , "Propeller3" , "Propeller4"

I want to add this 4 objects to allObjects
So it will rotate only the 4 properllers of this object the script is attached to. Since i'm cloning the object to many more i don't want to use FindByTag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add all the children of the GameObject which content the script:

```
private void Start()
    {
        allObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            allObjects.Add(child.gameObject)
        }
    }
```

Other options in case you would like to add children from other gameObjects:

You can find GameObjects by name. And even children using the path. For example:

```
   aFinger = transform.Find("LeftShoulder/Arm/Hand/Finger");
```

In case your children has the names you gave as example, you could do something like:

```
String Prefix = Propeller;
String nameGO;

for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
   nameGO = Propeller + i;
   GameObject mGameObject = transform.Find("PathToChildren/nameGO");
  //Now rotate or do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's a one time call only I would suggest using this snippet :

```
// names you want to search for
string[] searchForNames = new string[] { "Propeller1" , "Propeller2" , "Propeller3" , "Propeller4" };

// list of objects that matches the search
List<GameObject> wantedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
// placeholder for all objects in the current scent
List<GameObject> allObjects = new List<GameObjects>();
// retrieve all objects from active scene ( wont retrieve objects marked with DontDestroyOnLoad from other scenes )
SceneManager.GetActiveScene()GetRootGameObjects( allObjects );
// iterate through all objects found in the current scene
foreach(GameObject obj in allObjects)
{
    // check if name is contained by searchForNames array
    if(searchForNames.Contains(obj.name))
    {
        // add to the matching list
        wantedObjects.Add(obj);
    }
}
```